# Модель безопасности и случай, когда вся техника пропала

Tags: безопасность, пароль

Менеджеры паролей, шифрованные контейнеры в облаке, двухфакторная аутентификация для доступа к важным аккаунтам. Всё это хорошо.

Но вот ситуация, которая вполне возможна: вся техника пропала. Вообще вся. Голышом высадился на далёком континенте. Там есть интернет. Но с собой нет ничего, ни флешки, ни бука, ни блокнота.

Появится новый чистый компьютер, телефон. Удастся ли легко восстановить доступ ко всем паролям и аккаунтам?

Выходит, вся приватная инфраструктура, в конечном итоге, завязана на простой-слабый пароль/фразу, которая держится в голове. Значит, есть риск, что этот единственный пароль будет взломан. Либо риск потерять всё, лишившись техники.

**Какие есть умные подходы к этой проблеме?**

Наскоро подумалось:

- несколько доверенных лиц, держащих отдельные части "мастер"-пароля - телефоны их помнишь наизусть, звонишь, собираешь части пароля, получаешь доступ к облаку, менеджеру паролей и т.п.;
- банковская ячейка с биометрической авторизацией – пришел в Швейцарский банк как Джейсон Борн с корабля, просканировали руку, выдали ящичек с флешкой и блокнотом;
- time-capsule письмо самому себе – знаешь, куда и когда оно придёт, там пароли. В обычном режиме незадолго до прихода письма все пароли меняются на новые и запускается новое письмо «в будущее»;
- фрагмент числа Пи, начиная с цифры, соотв. году рождения длиной равной дню – и другие экзотические способы легко запомнить сложный длинный пароль.

Comment: @sergiks, не получится, т.к. в большинстве банков идиотская двухфакторная авторизация, без опций и прочего (либо через телефон, либо через карточку с ключами). Но вообще, вся ваша жизнь находится в слабо защищенной оболочке, зачем переживать о слабом пароле.

Comment: @sergiks, а может просто записать ручкой на бумаге в нескольких экземплярах (+ некоторое количество телефонных номеров)?

Comment: @eicto Deutsche Bank, что частный, что корпоративный: логин, пароль, список кодов для авторизации операций (по 6 цифр, 100 кодов на листке - сканируется и хранится в эл. виде). Плохо, что если всё потерял, просто прийти в банк и доказать, что я это я по рисунку сосудов, нет возможности.

@avp вопрос в том, что человек оказывается без всего в новом месте. Без бумажек в т.ч. Телефоны и имена близких друзей, вероятно, помнит. Пару-тройку паролей тоже. Q: как организовать «квест» восстановления всех доступов в такой ситуации надёжно со всех точек зрения.

Answer (score 1):

Все просто - получаем доступ к облаку, в облаке лежит манагер паролей с БД паролей и вуаля.

P.S. У меня все так и сделано и уже срабатывало, когда приходилось все восстанавливать в далеком острове сидя в Интернет кафе. Dropbox - forever :)

Comment: У меня такая же схема сейчас, но пароли от db тоже сложные, в Keepass. Вот, думаю, где нужно таки ослабить пароли до запоминаемых.

Comment: @sergiks, у меня на VPS, самом Keepass и на критической почте стоят длинные passphrases, которые я помню наизусть, общим счетом не больше десяти штук. Стойкость остальных зависит от сервиса, от тех, где мне вообще наплевать на профиль, стоит преобразованное по довольно банальному алгоритму имя сервиса плюс кое-какая стандартная соль.

Comment: @Etki «помнить наизусть» обычно значит «не менять годами», что формально не есть хорошо, не так ли?

Comment: @sergiks, вообще да, но запоминать раз в полгода десяток новых фраз - на это нужно просто одно усилие воли.